# Problems with axis label and colorbar for pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

I used matlab2tikz to convert a figure from matlab to tikz. When I run this code, I get this addition $.10^-2$ in both X and Y axis. (see figure below ). In addition ytick of the colorbar is also not showing. Can anyone identify cause of the problems, and suggest me the solution.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage {tikz,pgfplots}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

  \begin{document}
  \newlength\figureheight
  \newlength\figurewidth   
  \setlength\figureheight{0.4 \columnwidth} 
  \setlength\figurewidth{0.4 \columnwidth} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[%
   width=\figurewidth,
   height=\figureheight,
   view={0}{90},
   colormap/bone,
   colorbar,
   colorbar/width =0.4cm,
   colorbar style ={at={(1.1,1)},
     font = \scriptsize,
  ytick={0,0.4,0.8},
  yticklabels={$0$,$0.4$,$0.8$}
  },
   scale only axis,
   ticklabel style ={font =\scriptsize},
   xmin=-0.02, xmax=0.02,
   xtick = {-0.02,0,0.02},
   xticklabels ={-$0.02$,$0$,$0.02$},
   xlabel={$v_x$ (m/s)},
   xlabel near ticks,
   font = \scriptsize,
   ymin=-0.02, ymax=0.02,
   ytick = {-0.02,0,0.02},
   yticklabels ={-$0.02$,$0$,$0.02$},
   ylabel={$v_y$ (m/s)},
   ylabel near ticks,
   font = \scriptsize,
   zmin=-1, zmax=1,
   zticklabels={\empty},
   ]

   \addplot3[%
   surf,
   shader=faceted,
   draw=black,
   point meta=explicit,
   mesh/rows=11]
   table[meta index=3,header=false] {
   -0.02 -0.02 0 0.08
   -0.02 -0.016 0 0.0724430811050993
   -0.02 -0.012 0 0.0659696900098826
   -0.02 -0.008 0 0.0609261848469113
   -0.02 -0.004 0 0.0576888204074238
   -0.02 0 0 0.0565685424949238
   -0.02 0.004 0 0.0576888204074238
   -0.02 0.008 0 0.0609261848469113
   -0.02 0.012 0 0.0659696900098826
   -0.02 0.016 0 0.0724430811050993
   -0.02 0.02 0 0.08
   -0.016 -0.02 0 0.0724430811050993
   -0.016 -0.016 0 0.064
   -0.016 -0.012 0 0.0565685424949238
   -0.016 -0.008 0 0.0505964425626941
   -0.016 -0.004 0 0.0466476151587624
   -0.016 0 0 0.045254833995939
   -0.016 0.004 0 0.0466476151587624
   -0.016 0.008 0 0.0505964425626941
   -0.016 0.012 0 0.0565685424949238
   -0.016 0.016 0 0.064
   -0.016 0.02 0 0.0724430811050993
   -0.012 -0.02 0 0.0659696900098826
   -0.012 -0.016 0 0.0565685424949238
   -0.012 -0.012 0 0.048
   -0.012 -0.008 0 0.0407921561087423
   -0.012 -0.004 0 0.0357770876399966
   -0.012 0 0 0.0339411254969543
   -0.012 0.004 0 0.0357770876399966
   -0.012 0.008 0 0.0407921561087423
   -0.012 0.012 0 0.048
   -0.012 0.016 0 0.0565685424949238
   -0.012 0.02 0 0.0659696900098826
   -0.008 -0.02 0 0.0609261848469113
   -0.008 -0.016 0 0.0505964425626941
   -0.008 -0.012 0 0.0407921561087423
   -0.008 -0.008 0 0.032
   -0.008 -0.004 0 0.025298221281347
   -0.008 0 0 0.0226274169979695
    -0.008 0.004 0 0.025298221281347
   -0.008 0.008 0 0.032
   -0.008 0.012 0 0.0407921561087423
   -0.008 0.016 0 0.0505964425626941
   -0.008 0.02 0 0.0609261848469113
   -0.004 -0.02 0 0.0576888204074238
   -0.004 -0.016 0 0.0466476151587624
   -0.004 -0.012 0 0.0357770876399966
   -0.004 -0.008 0 0.025298221281347
   -0.004 -0.004 0 0.016
   -0.004 0 0 0.0113137084989848
   -0.004 0.004 0 0.016
   -0.004 0.008 0 0.025298221281347
   -0.004 0.012 0 0.0357770876399966
   -0.004 0.016 0 0.0466476151587624
   -0.004 0.02 0 0.0576888204074238
    0 -0.02 0 0.0565685424949238
    0 -0.016 0 0.045254833995939
    0 -0.012 0 0.0339411254969543
    0 -0.008 0 0.0226274169979695
    0 -0.004 0 0.0113137084989848
    0 0 0 0
    0 0.004 0 0.0113137084989848
    0 0.008 0 0.0226274169979695
    0 0.012 0 0.0339411254969543
    0 0.016 0 0.045254833995939
    0 0.02 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.004 -0.02 0 0.0576888204074238
    0.004 -0.016 0 0.0466476151587624
    0.004 -0.012 0 0.0357770876399966
    0.004 -0.008 0 0.025298221281347
    0.004 -0.004 0 0.016
    0.004 0 0 0.0113137084989848
    0.004 0.004 0 0.016
    0.004 0.008 0 0.025298221281347
    0.004 0.012 0 0.0357770876399966
    0.004 0.016 0 0.0466476151587624
    0.004 0.02 0 0.0576888204074238
    0.008 -0.02 0 0.0609261848469113
    0.008 -0.016 0 0.0505964425626941
    0.008 -0.012 0 0.0407921561087423
    0.008 -0.008 0 0.032
    0.008 -0.004 0 0.025298221281347
    0.008 0 0 0.0226274169979695
    0.008 0.004 0 0.025298221281347
    0.008 0.008 0 0.032
    0.008 0.012 0 0.0407921561087423
    0.008 0.016 0 0.0505964425626941
    0.008 0.02 0 0.0609261848469113
    0.012 -0.02 0 0.0659696900098826
    0.012 -0.016 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.012 -0.012 0 0.048
    0.012 -0.008 0 0.0407921561087423
    0.012 -0.004 0 0.0357770876399966
    0.012 0 0 0.0339411254969543
    0.012 0.004 0 0.0357770876399966
    0.012 0.008 0 0.0407921561087423
    0.012 0.012 0 0.048
    0.012 0.016 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.012 0.02 0 0.0659696900098826
    0.016 -0.02 0 0.0724430811050993
    0.016 -0.016 0 0.064
    0.016 -0.012 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.016 -0.008 0 0.0505964425626941
    0.016 -0.004 0 0.0466476151587624
    0.016 0 0 0.045254833995939
    0.016 0.004 0 0.0466476151587624
    0.016 0.008 0 0.0505964425626941
    0.016 0.012 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.016 0.016 0 0.064
    0.016 0.02 0 0.0724430811050993
    0.02 -0.02 0 0.08
    0.02 -0.016 0 0.0724430811050993
    0.02 -0.012 0 0.0659696900098826
    0.02 -0.008 0 0.0609261848469113
    0.02 -0.004 0 0.0576888204074238
    0.02 0 0 0.0565685424949238
    0.02 0.004 0 0.0576888204074238
    0.02 0.008 0 0.0609261848469113
    0.02 0.012 0 0.0659696900098826
    0.02 0.016 0 0.0724430811050993
    0.02 0.02 0 0.08
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Is this the output from `matlab2tikz`, or did you manually change some things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `matlab2tikz` seems to hardcode the tick labels.

Ordinarily, I would recommend to remove the `xtick` and `xticklabels` keys, but since this is the output of an external program, it's preferable to use an approach that doesn't require altering the code directly.

To remove the axis multiplier, use

```
\pgfplotsset{scaled ticks = false}
```

somewhere before the `axis` environment.

To get the ticks for the color bar, you need to unset the `ytick` option, and you need to deactivate the `colorbar style` key (otherwise the options given within the `axis` environment have higher precedence). To do this, you can put

```
\pgfplotsset{
    colorbar style/.code={},
    every colorbar/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed
    }
}
```

before the `axis` environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. How do I decrease the distance between the colorbar and the figure?

Comment: @Ansu: You can move the colorbar closer to the plot using something like `\pgfplotsset{
    colorbar style/.code={},
    every colorbar/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        at={(1.05,1)}
    }
}`, where the `1.05` specifies that the colorbar should be placed with a gap of 5% of the axis width.

Comment: +1 for `colorbar style/.code={}`. I did not know you could do this!